# Struggling with conversions and using arrays to specify a random item to give to a user

Tags: java

I am currently learning to code in Java so any constructive criticism is much appreciated. (Please try to dumb things down a little. I'm not too sure on a lot of things as of yet. But I am getting there.
What I am trying to do at the moment is to create a plugin that when a command is run, a number 1-10 is generated and according to the array, that item will be given to the user. But there is something not working and not allowing me to change from String to Material. I know and understand the error. But don't know how it would be fixed. Thank you for the help! :)

```
package me.nubzz;

import java.util.Random;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.*;
import org.bukkit.entity.Item;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.*;

public class MysteryGift {

    Random rnd = new Random();

        public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        String[] itemArray = {"Apple", "IronIngot", "GoldIngot", "Diamond", "Carrot", "IronShovel", "IronPickaxe", "IronSword", "IronAxe", "IronHoe"};

        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gift") && sender instanceof Player) {

            int giftn = rnd.nextInt(10) + 1;

            Player player = (Player) sender;

            PlayerInventory inventory = player.getInventory();

            String pItem = itemArray[giftn];

            inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(pItem, 1));

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

> The constructor ItemStack(String, int) is undefined

Is the error I receive.

> inventory.addItem(new ItemStack(pItem, 1));

Is the line it is on.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the ItemStack class does not have a constructor, which accepts a String and int parameter. You need to define such a constructor in the ItemStack class or use other parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities here:

1. `ItemStack` does not have a constructor.
2. `ItemStack` does have a constructor, but not one that takes a `String` and `int` as parameters.
3. `ItemStack` does have a constructor that accepts these parameters, but they are in the wrong order (i.e., it takes `int` first and then `String`).
4. `ItemStack` is in another package which has not been imported.

Answer (score 0):

An `ItemStack` in Bukkit is almost always instantiated using a `Material` "type" (or an ID, although that is deprecated). In your case, since the item amount is always one, you could use the `ItemStack(Material mat)` constructor to make an ItemStack with an amount of one to give to the player.

If you really want to save the types of items in `String` format you could use the `Material.getMaterial(String name)` method to retrieve the corresponding material for a given name, although you will have to use the built in Bukkit names for the materials (example: "IRON_SPADE" instead of "IronShovel").

Also note that the way you are creating the index that you use to retrieve a random element in the array will eventually result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The first element in an array has index zero. Your `String` array has ten elements, thus contains indices zero through nine. The method `random.getInt(int)` returns a pseudo-random integer between zero and the specified integer minus one (exclusive of the provided integer). Therefore `rnd.nextInt(10)` will return values between zero and nine (which is all you need for your array). Adding one to that index now makes the index have a value between one and ten, meaning it will never retrieve the first element and will eventually try to retrieve an element at index ten (which does not exist) and then throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I rewrote your method to give an example of how it could look, hope that helps:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
    if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("gift") && sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender; // Cast player
        int index = rnd.nextInt(10); // Pseudorandom value between 0 and 9
        // The array with material enumerators (10 elements, indices from 0 to 9)
        Material[] materials = {Material.APPLE, Material.IRON_INGOT, Material.GOLD_INGOT, Material.DIAMOND, Material.CARROT, Material.IRON_SPADE, Material.IRON_PICKAXE, Material.IRON_SWORD, Material.IRON_AXE, Material.IRON_HOE};
        player.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(materials[index])); // Add a new ItemStack to the player's inventory using the selected material
    }
    return false;
}
```